# Differentiability and Convergent Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ with $a= \sup\{|f'(x)| : x \in \mathbb{R} \} < 1$. Let $s_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $s_n = f(s_{n-1})$. Show that $(s_n)$ is convergent.

Hint from my book: Show $(s_n)$ is Cauchy by showing that $|s_{n+1} - s_n| \leq a|s_n-s_{n-1}|$.

First I noted that $\displaystyle \frac{|s_{n+1} - s_n|}{|s_n - s_{n-1}|} = \frac{|f(s_n) - f(s_{n-1})|}{|s_n - s_{n-1}|}$. By the Mean Value Theorem I know  that there exists an $x$ between $s_{n-1}$ and $s_n$ such that $\displaystyle f'(x) = \frac{f(s_n) - f(s_{n-1})}{s_n - s_{n-1}}$. Then I can write $\left\vert \frac{f(s_n) - f(s_{n-1})}{s_n - s_{n-1}} \right\vert = |f'(x)| \leq \sup |f'(x)| = a$. So I've established the hint that $|s_{n+1} - s_n| \leq a|s_n - s_{n-1}|$.

Now in order to show that $(s_n)$ is Cauchy: $(\forall \varepsilon >0)(\exists N \in \mathbb{N})$ such that $(\forall n>m\geq N) \implies |s_n - s_m| < \varepsilon$. Then $|s_n - s_m| = |(s_n - s_{n-1}) + \cdots + (s_{m+1} - s_m)| \leq |s_n - s_{n-1}| + \cdots +|s_{m+1} - s_m| \leq |s_1 - s_0| (a^n + a^{n-1} + \cdots + a^{m+1})$

which is justified by the hint.

This is where I got stuck. I wasn't quite sure how to bound the last expression to solve for $n$ in terms of $\varepsilon$. I considered $\displaystyle \sum^n_{k=m+1} a^k = \frac{1-a^{n-m}}{1-a}$ since $a<1$ and that got me to $\displaystyle |s_1 - s_0| \left\vert \frac{1-a^{n-m}}{1-a} \right\vert$ which I want to make less than $\varepsilon$. But now I have to deal with $m$.

Could someone give me some feedback and/or hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k=\frac{1}{1-a}$$

is convergent. Then by Cauchy's convergence criterion for this series we have that $\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}a^k<\epsilon$ for $n$, $m$ large.

Comment: How would I solve for $n$ in that case?

Comment: Well, I wrote it with an awkward wording first. Well, you actually get $|s_n-s_m|<\epsilon$, which is what you need.

Comment: @RBG: I see what you mean now. Thanks!